# ABPeoplePicker: Reset Custom Navigationbar Appearance

Tags: iphone, reset, abpeoplepickerview, uiappearance

I am using a custom appearance of my UINavigationBar, the UIBarBattunItems and the BackButton. Additionally, I am using Apple's ABPeoplePicker to let the user choose from some contacts. My problem is that I would like to reset the appearance to the default appearance but only while the people picker is presented modally.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I am presenting my people picker in the following way.

```
//showing people picker do identify owner of the certificate
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code before the present picker.

```
picker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```